# Modules registration in Prism 7.1

Tags: wpf, prism

In Prism 7.1, the IModule interface has changed from version 6.3, and now exposes the two methods **RegisterTypes** (IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) and **OnInitialized** (IContainerProvider containerProvider). I ask forgiveness, but I cannot understand how I have to register the Views implemented in the Module. it's probably so simple that I can not see the solution to the problem. Can you give me an example to finally make me understand how I should do? Wherever I looked, I found only examples regarding version 6.3, which I know rather well ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's probably so simple that I can not see the solution to the problem

Just use `RegisterTypes` - registering a view is registering a type, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Prism 7.X introduces an abstraction around the DI Container. There were a number of reasons for this but the top two are:

1. Many of the support questions from the community to the Prism team revolved around how to do something with a container that has nothing to do with the Prism team.
2. By abstracting the container it makes scenarios around sharing code and swapping out containers easier.

It's also important to understand that by abstracting the Container we've also made changes to the Container Extensions responsible for registering Views. Specifically we now have them on the IContainerRegistry. So given the sample Prism 6.X Module here:

```
public class ModuleA
{
    private IUnityContainer _container { get; }

    public ModuleA(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // register stuff
        _container.RegisterViewForNavigation<ViewA>();

        // Setup Event listeners etc...
        var ea = _container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
    }
}
```

We would update this to:

```
public class ModuleA
{
    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        // Setup Event listeners etc...
        var ea = containerProvider.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        // register stuff
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA>();
    }
}
```